# How to add padding between Echarts heatmap items / pieces?

Tags: heatmap, echarts

I try to resemble the design of https://status.wistia.com/ so I would like to add padding between each heatmap's item / piece.

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=heatmap-cartesian&edit=1&reset=1

```js
/**
 ** Initialize
 */
const chartDom = document.getElementById('chart')
const chart = echarts.init(chartDom)

/**
 ** Data
 */
const data = [[0, 0, 5], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 6, 0], [0, 7, 0], [0, 8, 0], [0, 9, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 11, 2], [0, 12, 4], [0, 13, 1], [0, 14, 1], [0, 15, 3], [0, 16, 4], [0, 17, 6], [0, 18, 4], [0, 19, 4], [0, 20, 3], [0, 21, 3], [0, 22, 2], [0, 23, 5], [1, 0, 7], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 4, 0], [1, 5, 0], [1, 6, 0], [1, 7, 0], [1, 8, 0], [1, 9, 0], [1, 10, 5], [1, 11, 2], [1, 12, 2], [1, 13, 6], [1, 14, 9], [1, 15, 11], [1, 16, 6], [1, 17, 7], [1, 18, 8], [1, 19, 12], [1, 20, 5], [1, 21, 5], [1, 22, 7], [1, 23, 2], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [2, 3, 0], [2, 4, 0], [2, 5, 0], [2, 6, 0], [2, 7, 0], [2, 8, 0], [2, 9, 0], [2, 10, 3], [2, 11, 2], [2, 12, 1], [2, 13, 9], [2, 14, 8], [2, 15, 10], [2, 16, 6], [2, 17, 5], [2, 18, 5], [2, 19, 5], [2, 20, 7], [2, 21, 4], [2, 22, 2], [2, 23, 4], [3, 0, 7], [3, 1, 3], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0], [3, 4, 0], [3, 5, 0], [3, 6, 0], [3, 7, 0], [3, 8, 1], [3, 9, 0], [3, 10, 5], [3, 11, 4], [3, 12, 7], [3, 13, 14], [3, 14, 13], [3, 15, 12], [3, 16, 9], [3, 17, 5], [3, 18, 5], [3, 19, 10], [3, 20, 6], [3, 21, 4], [3, 22, 4], [3, 23, 1], [4, 0, 1], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 0], [4, 3, 0], [4, 4, 0], [4, 5, 1], [4, 6, 0], [4, 7, 0], [4, 8, 0], [4, 9, 2], [4, 10, 4], [4, 11, 4], [4, 12, 2], [4, 13, 4], [4, 14, 4], [4, 15, 14], [4, 16, 12], [4, 17, 1], [4, 18, 8], [4, 19, 5], [4, 20, 3], [4, 21, 7], [4, 22, 3], [4, 23, 0], [5, 0, 2], [5, 1, 1], [5, 2, 0], [5, 3, 3], [5, 4, 0], [5, 5, 0], [5, 6, 0], [5, 7, 0], [5, 8, 2], [5, 9, 0], [5, 10, 4], [5, 11, 1], [5, 12, 5], [5, 13, 10], [5, 14, 5], [5, 15, 7], [5, 16, 11], [5, 17, 6], [5, 18, 0], [5, 19, 5], [5, 20, 3], [5, 21, 4], [5, 22, 2], [5, 23, 0], [6, 0, 1], [6, 1, 0], [6, 2, 0], [6, 3, 0], [6, 4, 0], [6, 5, 0], [6, 6, 0], [6, 7, 0], [6, 8, 0], [6, 9, 0], [6, 10, 1], [6, 11, 0], [6, 12, 2], [6, 13, 1], [6, 14, 3], [6, 15, 4], [6, 16, 0], [6, 17, 0], [6, 18, 0], [6, 19, 0], [6, 20, 1], [6, 21, 2], [6, 22, 2], [6, 23, 6]]
    .map((item) => [item[1], item[0], item[2] || '-'])
    
/**
 ** Option
 */
const option = {
  tooltip: {
    position: 'top'
  },
  grid: {
    height: '50%',
    top: '10%'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a', '7a', '8a', '9a', '10a', '11a', '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p', '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'],
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday', 'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'],
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  visualMap: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    calculable: true,
    orient: 'horizontal',
    left: 'center',
    bottom: '15%'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Punch Card',
      type: 'heatmap',
      data: data,
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        itemStyle: {
          shadowBlur: 10,
          shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

/**
 ** Render Chart
 */
chart.setOption(option)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.2/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha512-VdqgeoWrVJcsDXFlQEKqE5MyhaIgB9yXUVaiUa8DR2J4Lr1uWcFm+ZH/YnzV5WqgKf4GPyHQ64vVLgzqGIchyw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="chart" style="width: 800px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

I tried many settings such as itemGap, padding but I was not able to get a white space next to each cell in the heatmap.

[image: need it]

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

The ECharts provides the option to format elements, allowing you to add outlines to the elements, and you can also customize their size and color. I don't believe this solution is perfect, but it produces the desired result and currently, this is the only option available

```js
const option = {
  // ...
  series: [{
    itemStyle: {
      borderWidth: 5,
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
    },
  }],
  // ...
}
```

[`series-heatmap.itemStyle.borderWidth`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-heatmap.itemStyle.borderWidth) - ECharts Docs
[`series-heatmap.itemStyle.borderColor`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-heatmap.itemStyle.borderColor) - ECharts Docs

To make the X and Y axis labels (`lineStyle`) visible, you need to move the axes further away using the offset value. By setting the `axisLine.onZero` to false, the axis itself will move away from the chart, preventing the white border from obstructing it.

```js
const option = {
  // ...
  xAxis: {
    // set margin between X axis and chart
    offset: 5,// need minimum value of borderWidth or higher
    axisLine: {
      onZero: false,
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    // set margin between Y axis and chart
    offset: 5, // need minimum value of borderWidth or higher
    axisLine: {
      onZero: false,
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

[`xAxis.offset`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.offset) - ECharts Docs
[`xAxis.axisLine.onZero`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLine.onZero) - ECharts Docs
[`yAxis.offset`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.offset) - ECharts Docs
[`yAxis.axisLine.onZero`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.axisLine.onZero) - ECharts Docs

### Example

```js
/**
 ** Initialize
 */
const chartDom = document.getElementById('chart')
const chart = echarts.init(chartDom)

/**
 ** Data
 */
const data = [[0, 0, 5], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 6, 0], [0, 7, 0], [0, 8, 0], [0, 9, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 11, 2], [0, 12, 4], [0, 13, 1], [0, 14, 1], [0, 15, 3], [0, 16, 4], [0, 17, 6], [0, 18, 4], [0, 19, 4], [0, 20, 3], [0, 21, 3], [0, 22, 2], [0, 23, 5], [1, 0, 7], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 4, 0], [1, 5, 0], [1, 6, 0], [1, 7, 0], [1, 8, 0], [1, 9, 0], [1, 10, 5], [1, 11, 2], [1, 12, 2], [1, 13, 6], [1, 14, 9], [1, 15, 11], [1, 16, 6], [1, 17, 7], [1, 18, 8], [1, 19, 12], [1, 20, 5], [1, 21, 5], [1, 22, 7], [1, 23, 2], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [2, 3, 0], [2, 4, 0], [2, 5, 0], [2, 6, 0], [2, 7, 0], [2, 8, 0], [2, 9, 0], [2, 10, 3], [2, 11, 2], [2, 12, 1], [2, 13, 9], [2, 14, 8], [2, 15, 10], [2, 16, 6], [2, 17, 5], [2, 18, 5], [2, 19, 5], [2, 20, 7], [2, 21, 4], [2, 22, 2], [2, 23, 4], [3, 0, 7], [3, 1, 3], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0], [3, 4, 0], [3, 5, 0], [3, 6, 0], [3, 7, 0], [3, 8, 1], [3, 9, 0], [3, 10, 5], [3, 11, 4], [3, 12, 7], [3, 13, 14], [3, 14, 13], [3, 15, 12], [3, 16, 9], [3, 17, 5], [3, 18, 5], [3, 19, 10], [3, 20, 6], [3, 21, 4], [3, 22, 4], [3, 23, 1], [4, 0, 1], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 0], [4, 3, 0], [4, 4, 0], [4, 5, 1], [4, 6, 0], [4, 7, 0], [4, 8, 0], [4, 9, 2], [4, 10, 4], [4, 11, 4], [4, 12, 2], [4, 13, 4], [4, 14, 4], [4, 15, 14], [4, 16, 12], [4, 17, 1], [4, 18, 8], [4, 19, 5], [4, 20, 3], [4, 21, 7], [4, 22, 3], [4, 23, 0], [5, 0, 2], [5, 1, 1], [5, 2, 0], [5, 3, 3], [5, 4, 0], [5, 5, 0], [5, 6, 0], [5, 7, 0], [5, 8, 2], [5, 9, 0], [5, 10, 4], [5, 11, 1], [5, 12, 5], [5, 13, 10], [5, 14, 5], [5, 15, 7], [5, 16, 11], [5, 17, 6], [5, 18, 0], [5, 19, 5], [5, 20, 3], [5, 21, 4], [5, 22, 2], [5, 23, 0], [6, 0, 1], [6, 1, 0], [6, 2, 0], [6, 3, 0], [6, 4, 0], [6, 5, 0], [6, 6, 0], [6, 7, 0], [6, 8, 0], [6, 9, 0], [6, 10, 1], [6, 11, 0], [6, 12, 2], [6, 13, 1], [6, 14, 3], [6, 15, 4], [6, 16, 0], [6, 17, 0], [6, 18, 0], [6, 19, 0], [6, 20, 1], [6, 21, 2], [6, 22, 2], [6, 23, 6]]
    .map((item) => [item[1], item[0], item[2] || '-'])

/**
 ** Option
 */
const option = {
  tooltip: {
    position: 'top'
  },
  grid: {
    height: '50%',
    top: '10%'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ["12a", "1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a", "11a", "12p", "1p", "2p", "3p", "4p", "5p", "6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "11p"],
    offset: 5,
    axisLine: {
      onZero: false,
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ["Saturday", "Friday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday", "Monday", "Sunday"],
    offset: 5,
    axisLine: {
      onZero: false,
    }
  },
  visualMap: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    calculable: true,
    orient: 'horizontal',
    left: 'center',
    bottom: '15%'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Punch Card',
      type: 'heatmap',
      data: data,
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      // Item Default Style
      itemStyle: {
        borderWidth: 5,
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
      },
      // When Hover
      emphasis: {
        // Item Hover Style
        itemStyle: {
          borderWidth: 5,
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

/**
 ** Render Chart
 */
chart.setOption(option)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.2/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha512-VdqgeoWrVJcsDXFlQEKqE5MyhaIgB9yXUVaiUa8DR2J4Lr1uWcFm+ZH/YnzV5WqgKf4GPyHQ64vVLgzqGIchyw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="chart" style="width: 800px; height: 300px;"></div>
```